# Screen turn into dark when set UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled to false

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I want screen always light when playing audio, and turn dark when complete the audio and I do not tap the screen after two minutes(i have set auto-lock in setting), implement code as the following.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
    }
```

But the result is screen turn dark immediately when finish one audio which is more than two minutes.

How to fix it ,or is this ios bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there isn't any opportunity to reset idle timer thus your device goes off immediately after the `isIdleTimerDisabled`-property set.

Yet you still can try to implement your own timer to turn it off in right time.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + interval, execute: {
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
    })
}
```

Unfortunately, there still isn't any way to check current `idleTimer` time to calculate `interval` value dynamically.